# Django crontab not working in elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My cron jobs work fine on localhost but when i deploy they are not getting added. 
The following settings.py:

```
CRONJOBS = [
('*/1 * * * *', 'push.cron.my_scheduled_job')
```

]
In development, cron works perfectly by doing this:

1. python manage.py crontab add
2. python manage.py crontab run 2e847f370afca8feeddaa55d5094d128

But when i deploy it to server using.. the cron jobs don't get added automatically. How do i add the crob jobs to the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron jobs running on localhost are not related to your server. You will need to run them separately pretty much in the same manner as you do in your local.

```
## I am assuming that you already activated your virtual env 

python manage.py crontab add #returns a hash
python manage.py crontab run "hash" # put the has here without quotes
```

You could automate by writing and running some sort of bash script.

I will recommend that you use [celery-beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) instead of crontab if you want some automation.

Comment: This doesn’t really seems like

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to get this working.

First I wrote the script as a "Django Custom Management Command".

Then I established a SSH connection, which starts at directory "/home/ec2-user", and entered "crontab -e" to edit the crontab.

In the crontab file, just add the following line (replace MY_CUSTOM_MANAGEMENT_COMMAND with your own file):

- - - - - source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py MY_CUSTOM_MANAGEMENT_COMMAND

Then you're done.

You didn't mention in your question, but there's something I would like to point out, because I've seen it in some well known blogs: you don't need a worker tier for this, the crontab works just fine in the web server tier. Use the worker tier if you have some heavy background processing.